# string.matchAll(regex) behaving strange in browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I was using a regular expression to match markdown in node.js. But I'm trying to run it in a react.js app whith little success...

```
  const regex = /(\*\*\*|___|\*\*|\*|__|\[.*?\]\([^)]*\))(.*?)(\1|$)/g;

  const matches = markdown.matchAll(regex);

  for (const match of matches) {
    console.log(match);
  }
```

When I run the code in node.js with sample input: `'normal text **bold** *italic* normal'`

I get the output:

```
[
  '**bold**',
  '**',
  'bold',
  '**',
  index: 12,
  input: 'normal text **bold** *italic* normal',
  groups: undefined
]
[
  '*italic*',
  '*',
  'italic',
  '*',
  index: 21,
  input: 'normal text **bold** *italic* normal',
  groups: undefined
]
```

But when I run the same code in my react app, in edge (120.0.2210.133) and chrom (120.0.6099.225)

`matches` logs as:

```
RegExpStringIterator {}
```

When I try to iterate over it and log each item

```
for (const match of matches) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

I got nothing, unlike in node.js

But according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll I should get a similar output as I did in node.js, and according to https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_matchall both chrome and endge should fully support `matchAll`

Just for sanity check, I tried running the code directly in the chrome terminal, with same result as the react app
[image]

What's going on?

Comment: On the MDN link you provide it states: *The matchAll() method of String values returns an iterator* ... returns an `iterator` - you need to iterate an iterator to get the results (which is what `[...matches]` does for you)

Comment: Can you provide exact Node version and code that you tried? Running `"foo".matchAll(/o/g);` gives me exact same result in Node v20.5.1 as in current Edge/Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: I put your code in runkit.com which claims to run node.js and it also gave the `RegExpStringIterator {}` output.

Comment: Voting to close as "Need debugging details". I also cannot replicate the behaviour on Node v21.1.0 using the code exactly as given.

Comment: I agree, yet I would still like to see OP getting to the root of their problem. Wild guess is that they had some aggressive String.prototype.replaceAll override (presumably some ancient polyfill) or something like that going on in his Node environment, what caused the discrepancy. @RasmusPuls, would you mind trying the synthetic test in your Node environments ("*clean*" and app), to confirm or eliminate such possibility?

Comment: Hi, sorry for absence... Inside my react code I did: 
const md = 'normal text \*\*bold\*\* \*italic\* normal';
const matches = md.matchAll(regex);
for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(match); // which didn't log anything, despite `matches` being `RegExpStringIterator {}`
}
But in node.js it would log each `match` element. But after spreadding `matches` inside square brackets (my answer below) seems to have done some sort of casting, because now it does log the match elements - both in react and node.js. Issue might be cause by my react app bundler or transpiler.... im not sure.

Comment: @RasmusPuls Here's a wild guess: Did you use the same regex [more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800)?

Comment:  I have used it in several contexts, unit tests, pasted in browser terminal, run in react app, run on node.js app. This is not the first time.... When I read your comment, a very far deep memory arised. And I have a feeling this wont be the last time I run into this trap! Anyway, thanks for assissting solving the mystery

Answer (score 0):

Okay... this seems to be because the `RegExpStringIterator` works differently in browser than it does in node.js.

I replicated the example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll By spreading the result inside an array:

```
  const regex = /(\*\*\*|___|\*\*|\*|__|\[.*?\]\([^)]*\))(.*?)(\1|$)/g;

  const matches = [...markdown.matchAll(regex)];
```

And this seems to behave the same in browser as it does in node ✌️

[image]

Comment: "*[...] the RegExpStringIterator works differently in browser than it does in node.js*": Chrome uses the same JS engine ([v8](https://v8.dev/)) as Node, so that should not happen; `.matchAll()` always return an iterator of matches.

Comment: Yea, I can't explain it. Something might happen with my react code before it reaches to browser - because it still behaves differently. I updated the question with a little more detail.